# Automate Tomcat adding to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, tomcat

I'm trying to write a script (Perl) that will automate the adding of Tomcat server for a Java project under Eclipse.

The project is checked out via SVN, and I want, once the project is downloaded via SVN, to run a script that will automatically configure the remaining bits of the project. In this context, I need to find how can I edit which Eclipse's configuration files to automate the adding of a Tomcat server. Actually the script will also modify other configuration files, but I'm facing a hard time trying to find which files to edit and how to add Tomcat.

Any insights will be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really clear for me, what you want. Do you want to add your project to an existing manually created tomcat server when you check out your project, or you want to create a tomcat server instance? If the second, after creating the server instance, what else do you want to do? What do you mean by "remaining bits" of project config?

Comment: Unzip eclipse in two separate folders. Add tomcat configuration in one eclipse instance. Use a folder comparison tool to compare these two eclipse installations and see which files got changed.

Comment: @Gabor: neither one. I think the question is pretty clear: I want to automate the whole server creation process by a script. Usman: thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: done your suggestion. The problem is that there are a bunch of binary files I can't compare. Even if I moved everything I found, still no go as the Server folder does not appear in Eclipse...

Comment: Some explanation for downvoting this **old** question would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for eclipse called Escripts. You can create xml like scripts to automate actions like doing wizard actions. I tried to check the documentation, but the homepage of the Escripts is giving back http 500 for me (http://escripts.sf.net). I have written a mail to the author, if he answers, I will let you know. The update site looks like working (uncheck the categorize by groups to see the uncategorized plugin): http://escripts.sf.net/updates .

Some examples you can found at http://escripts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/escripts/trunk/net.sf.escripts.tests/src/net/sf/escripts/tests/

What you should enter in the script is a wizard with id org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.new.server. The plugin, that is containing it is org.eclipse.wst.server.ui. Take a look at the plugin.xml in that plugin. Without the documentation, this is what I can remember of.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting, I'll try this. Still no go on the homepage either the updates (error 403). The SF homepage works though (http://sourceforge.net/projects/escripts/).

Comment: Wasn't able to find that plugin :(

Comment: You can download the source and build it. http://escripts.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/escripts/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following files in the Eclipse workspace?

.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs

I took the following files and dropped them into a new instance of eclipse and it created the Tomcat server under Server->Runtime Environment.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9591144/StackOverflow/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9591144/StackOverflow/org.eclipse.jdt.launching.prefs
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9591144/StackOverflow/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9591144/StackOverflow/org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs

Comment: I guess you mean .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings directory, org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs & org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs files. I've created those, but that's not enough. For example, there's a "Server" project that's created as well (which is not enough along with those files either...)... If you want I can post everything I've created and won't work.

Comment: Worth a try.  Are you getting anything at all to populate in the UI?

Comment: Don't know how I missed that other prefs file.  I was asking if you were able to get a Tomcat server to show up in the Properties->Server->Runtime Environment.

Comment: Sorry for lateness KevinO. Yes it does show when I edit quite a few files, but when I try to run it, it says there's no runtime configuration.